# Turf JS (node) Buffer multiple points

Tags: node.js, gis, geospatial, mapbox, turfjs

I am trying to buffer all points in a geojson file using turf. There are 50 points.  My script produces and output geojson file as intended, but QGIS wont display the resulting geojson file.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
var turf = require('turf');
var fs = require('fs');

var points = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('points.geojson')).features;

bufferlist = [];

for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) { 
    console.log(i);
    buff = turf.buffer((points[i]), .001);
    bufferlist.push(buff);
}


var bufferOut = turf.featurecollection(bufferlist);

fs.writeFileSync( "bufferOut.geojson", JSON.stringify(bufferOut));
console.log('Done');
```

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: can you paste a copy of the result here? just a sample would suffice.

Comment: The output Geojson looks like this (I abbreviated the coordinate list):                                                                   {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.684958143853,41.909863932918],[-87.684977358573,41.90966884259],    ..........                     [-87.68495814385358,41.90986393291892]]]},"properties":{}}]}},"properties":{}},{"type":"Feature","geometry": .......

Comment: My Mistake, pasted the wrong thing. Output looks like this:                                                              {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.68495814385358,41.90986393291892], .....[-87.68495814385358,41.90986393291892]]]},"properties":{}}]},{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.65431884777787,41.908245534895016].....

Comment: looks like valid GeoJSON. Have you tried to put it through a geojson validator?

Comment: http://geojsonlint.com/

Comment: It looks like you have nested feature collections. This isn't officially supported via the GeoJSON spec. Some applications support it and some don't. It looks like maybe QGIS possibly doesn't. Try to transform buffer out into a flattened array of feature collections if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and this line gives an error:

```
var bufferOut = turf.featurecollection(bufferlist);
```

I think the function `featurecollection` should be in camelCase `featureCollection`. I did that in my code and it worked.